# Optimal way to estimate date range of an ImageCollection in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, date

What is a most straightfoward way to get a date range of an `ee.ImageCollection` as formatted date strings?

For example, `ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT04/C01/T1_32DAY_EVI').get('date_range')` returns `[398044800000,756259200000]`, so first I need to cast both items into `ee.Date` and then `format()` or `print()` them to get `1982-08-13` and `1993-12-19`, but I think there should be easier ways to estimate date range of a collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a 2 lines alternative

```js
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT04/C01/T1_32DAY_EVI')
var range = collection.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.minMax(), ["system:time_start"])
```

Answer (score 2):

You will always require a lot of casting in the Earth Engine. Either way, does this met your needs? Works for most collections. Also note that it shows slight different dates than the one of the image collection property.

```
var date1 = imageCollection.sort('system:time_start',true).first().date()
var date2 = imageCollection.sort('system:time_start',false).first().date()
print(date1, date2)
```

For your specific collection, the `date()` function somehow does not work. Try this work around (with more casting :) ). Maybe someone from Google can elaborate on why?

```
var date1 = ee.Date(imageCollection.sort('system:time_start',true).first().get('system:time_start'))
var date2 = ee.Date(imageCollection.sort('system:time_start',false).first().get('system:time_start'))
print(date1, date2)
```

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/9db606ff11d3b34b7a53828a5af61539)